# jQuery UI .effect() not work on if..else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to change size on draggable item if `position.left` more than 100 else it return to original size.
But if I add `else` statement, jqueryUI `effect()` not work.

```js
$("img").draggable({
  axis: "x",
  drag: function() {

    $("div").html($(this).position().left)
    if ($(this).position().left > 100) {
      $(this).effect("size", {
        to: {
          width: 200,
          height: 200
        }
      });
    } else {
      $(this).effect("size", {
        to: {
          width: 100,
          height: 100
        }
      });
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
<div></div>
```

But if I delete else its work properly.

```js
$("img").draggable({
  axis: "x",
  drag: function() {

    $("div").html($(this).position().left)
    if ($(this).position().left > 100) {
      $(this).effect("size", {
        to: {
          width: 200,
          height: 200
        }
      });
    } 
    

  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
<div></div>
```

How to use `.effect()` on `if..else` statement?

Answer (score 2):

This is working sometimes but it takes some time. If you use the stop event, I think it will work as you expected

https://jsfiddle.net/2jh2323v/

```
$("img").draggable({
  axis: "x",
  stop: function() {

    $("div").html($(this).position().left)
    if ($(this).position().left > 100) { console.log('if');
      $(this).effect("size", {
        to: {
          width: 200,
          height: 200
        }
      });
    } else{
      $(this).effect("size", {
        to: {
          width: 100,
         height: 100
        }

      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer I really appreciate it, but It not fulfill what I want. And there is unknown bug when `position.left` less than 100.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this, using css `transition`,

```js
$("img").draggable({
  axis: "x",
  drag: function() {

    $("div").html($(this).position().left)
    if ($(this).position().left > 100) {
      $(this).width(200);
    } else {
      $(this).width(100);
    }

  }
});
```

```css
img {
  transition:width 1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
  <div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `stop` in place of `drag`:

```js
$("img").draggable({
  axis: "x",
  stop: function( event, ui ){
    $("div").html($(ui.helper).position().left)
    if ($(ui.helper).position().left > 100) {
      $(ui.helper).effect("size", {
        to: {
          width: 200,
          height: 200
        }
      });
    } else {
      $(ui.helper).effect("size", {
        to: {
          width: 100,
          height: 100
        }
      });
    }

  }
});
```

```css
.ui-draggable{
top:0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
<div></div>
```